# extracting data from .mat file

Tags: matlab, extract, mat-file, matlab-load

I have a .mat file  which contains 4 variables. Each variable (A,B,C,D) is a cell which reads <59145x1 double>. I know that there are 59145x1 arrays in each variable but do not know how to access them, and all i can see the this one cell in each.

Can anyone help?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the load function to load the variable data into MATLAB. Try `help load` for details.

Now you simply need to use the `cell2mat` function to "access" the variables. For example:

```
>> a{1}=[1,2,3,4]

a = 

    [1x4 double]

>> cell2mat(a)

ans =

     1     2     3     4
```